# Bootstrap Footer: Trouble Centering The Social Media Icons

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been trying to center the Social media Icons for over an hour and I seem to go nowhere.
Below is the HTML code snippet.

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-footer">
      <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google-plus" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-youtube" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

And below is the CSS code snippet.

```css
.row-footer {
    background-color: #AfAfAf;
    margin:200px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is how its appearing on Google Chrome.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using the `navbar-nav` class you have to remove it's default `float:left` rule.

```
.navbar-nav {
  padding: 40px 10px;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Working Example 1:**

```css
.row-footer {
  background-color: #AfAfAf;
  margin: 200px auto;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
div.navbar-nav {
  padding: 40px 10px;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-footer">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google-plus" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-youtube" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
          <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

**Working Example 2:**

```css
.row-footer {
  background-color: #AfAfAf;
  margin: 200px 0;
}
.footer-nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
.footer-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div class="row-footer">
          <div class="footer-nav">
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google-plus" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-youtube" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block;` on the icon combined with `text-align:center` on icons container.

If there is going to be more children than just the icons, consider wrapping them into another `<div>`.

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is **updated** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLgfhs48/1/)

Comment: Tried. Still stays in the same place!

Comment: If by *tried* you mean the content of your question, then you did not, as what you are doing is giving `display: inline-block` to icons container, not every single icon. Try exactly the code I gave you, and see it for yourself in my updated jsfiddle. It does work.